# How to display the reference suggestions in TeXstudio when using cref and tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, texstudio, cleveref

Edit: this question is now [this feature request](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/3006) on TXS Github.

Very picky question. I am happily using TeXstudio, the tcolorbox package and cleveref. In TXS, typing `cref` triggers a popup menu where all the available labels are listed, and the user can directly choose the relevant one. This convenient system seems broken when using references to theorem boxes.

**Detailed case**
The example uses `tcolorbox`, `amsmath` (required for cleveref), `cleveref` and the library `theorems` of tcolorbox (everything is typed in the minimal working example).

The command `\newtcbtheorem` creates a new type of tcolorbox theorem box, as in

```
\newtcbtheorem[crefname={mybox}{myboxes}]{mybox}{My super theorem}{}{mybox}
```

Here, the first optional argument in `[]` will set the cleveref name, the argument `{mybox}` is the name of the box environment, `{My super theorem}` is the displayed name in the title, the empty argument `{}` is for the box options, and the last `{mybox}` is the prefix of references. When creating a box, for instance

```
\begin{mybox}{The title}{thelabel} 
    Hello
\end{mybox}
```

the first argument is the title of the box, and the second creates a reference that we can call by `\cref{mybox:thelabel}`. Everything in the latex part works well, but the editor does not seem to know that these labels exist, and the user need either to know all of its labels by heart, or to yoyo in the document.

Example in picture:
[image]

**Desired behavior**
To be able to see `mybox:thelabel` in the list of suggestions of the popup. Any help is appreciated!

**Versions** If relevant, I am using Ubuntu 22.04, TeXstudio 4.3.1, tcolorbox 5.0.2, amsmath v2.17l and cleveref v0.21.4.

**Working example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath} % required for cleverref
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[crefname={mybox}{myboxes}]{mybox}{My super theorem}{}{mybox}

\begin{document}

    Example of the question:
    \begin{mybox}{The title}{thelabel} 
        Hello
    \end{mybox}

    This is a nice document, what a superb result we have here:
    \begin{mybox}{Micchelli 1986}{micchelli}
        Let $D$ be a distance matrix, i.e. $D_{ij} = d(x_i,x_j)$ for $n$ distinct points $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ of an euclidian space. Then $D$ is invertible. 
    \end{mybox}
    
    This theorem applies for equations of the type
    \begin{align}\label{normalref}
        \sum_{i=1}^n c_i d(x_i, x_j) = 0 \quad\quad \forall 1 \leq j \leq n,
    \end{align}
    and the popup correctly displays the \texttt{normalref}: indeed, \cref{normalref} was displayed. However, although \cref{mybox:micchelli} works nicely, it was not displayed. 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very interested by this functionality, too :) Have you searched/posted on the TeXstudio GitHub page?

Comment: This feature is not supported in texstudio but you're welcome to make a feature request on the [Github page](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues)

Comment: Thank you, I'll do this!